# How to drag a folder to the side panel in Nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

I am trying to drag a folder (Example /var/www) to the side panel in Nautilus so when I open Nautilus I can just go to it quickly. I know that entering the folder I want to drag to the side panel and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will add this to the bookmark section of the panel but I want to drag it instead of doing the key combination. Is this possible and if yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drag a folder to the folders under Computer, then you will move the folder, but if you drag it to the Bookmarks section, then you will create a bookmark for it. This bookmark will also be used in the Files lens.